# How to organize strings through a sort method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This is a program that lets user input 6 random letters, and the program sorts these letters in order. Ex user inputs j, d, e, l, w, q and program outputs d, e, j, l, q, w.

Unfortunately the code freaks out and does not sort a thing. Note: I am using a GUI

Under public I created a class and an array to eventually house all inputted letters

```
class Abc {
        String letter;

        Abc (String _letter) {
           letter = _letter;
        }
    }

    ArrayList <Abc> alphabet = new ArrayList <Abc>(3); //note its 3, not 6 like in the example
```

After user types in a letter in a textField, they press the "addButton" which adds and saves the value in the array.

```
String letter = letterField.getText();

        //Store values in array 
        Abc a = new Abc(letter);
        alphabet.add(a);
```

Now for the actual 'sorting' part. Which takes place after user presses a "Play" button.

```
String[] abc = new String[3]; //LINE I FORGOT TO ADD

for (int k = 0; k < abc.length; k++) {
            abc[k] = letterField.getText();

             int x;
            for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
                // Asume first value is x
                x = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < abc.length; j++) {
                    //find smallest value in array (random)
                    if (abc[j].compareToIgnoreCase(abc[x]) < 0) {
                        x = j;
                    }
                }
                if (x != i) {
                    //swap the values if not in correct order
                    final String temp = abc[i];
                    abc[i] = abc[x];
                    abc[x] = temp;
                }
                textArea.append(abc[i] + "\n");// Output correct order
            }
        }
```

I had originally used this code to sort integers, the only difference between that program and this program is the int/String and this one I am currently working on allows the user to input the letters and the program does not randomize them like it did with the integer program.

I had thought this would be enough code to do the trick and organize some letters, but apparently not.

For the actually problem, when I input the letters and add them to the array and press "play" the program freaks and a lovely error pops up...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "d"
```

Note: 'd' being the last letter I inputted for the last time I tested the program...all of five seconds ago.

Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What line of your code causes the exception?

Comment: In Java, we typically use `char` to hold a single letter. This can be much more efficient that using the `String` class.

Comment: Nothing in the code you have given can throw a NumberFormatException. Please show the line where this occurs. Most likely it is a line that uses `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: Either this is a coincidence, or very close duplicate: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030737/how-to-switch-int-sort-to-string-sort

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).  See if the String's default [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method works for you.  If it does, it'll sort that way.  Just do this:

```
List<String> alphabet = new ArrayList<String>();
//populate with Strings
Collections.sort(alphabet);
```

And then your alphabet will be mutated to be in abc order.

As for your actual error, I can't figure out where that line is occurring (if you tell us where the stack trace points to, I could).  But it looks like you've got some code that is trying to convert a String into a Number, but the String doesn't represent a number.  Specifically, somewhere you're trying to turn "d" into a number.

Comment: While that's the optimal way to do this, the question looks like a homework assignment

Answer (score 0):

It appears that somewhere in your code you are trying to parse String into a number, and when your String contain letters the method throws exception. Search through your code for some parseInt() or alike.